# Realizing an archive like mailbox in exchange

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

An employee left the company but his e-mails should stay accessible for some colleagues. The user account has to be deleted (not only disabled). Exporting the mails to a PST is not wanted.

I would realize it in this way:

- convert user-mailbox to shared-mailbox
- assign an invalid adress (like name@company.invalid)
- grant access to the colleagues

Especially because of the invalid e-mail address I like the solution not good.

Is there a better way?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/create-a-litigation-hold

Comment: Public folder. Or 3rd party archiving software (e. g. Veritas Vault)